# Homebrew OpenSSL: rehash failed to verify, something is wrong

Tags: macos, ssl, openssl, homebrew

Just noticed 'You have mail' in shell prompt. Here is what is says:

```
$ mail
Mail version 8.1 6/6/93.  Type ? for help.
"/var/mail/pain": 1 message 1 new
>N  1 pain@nick.localdomai  Wed Apr  8 14:00  21/804   "Cron <pain@nick> /usr"
? 1
Message 1:
From pain@nick.localdomain  Wed Apr  8 14:00:03 2015
X-Original-To: pain
Delivered-To: pain@nick.localdomain
From: pain@nick.localdomain (Cron Daemon)
To: pain@nick.localdomain
Subject: Cron <pain@nick> /usr/local/Cellar/openssl-osx-ca/1.0.4/bin/openssl-osx-ca /usr/local/bin/brew
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=pain>
X-Cron-Env: <USER=pain>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/Users/pain>
Date: Wed,  8 Apr 2015 14:00:01 +0700 (ICT)

Usage error; try -help.
rehash failed to verify, something is wrong
check /tmp/openssl-osx-ca.cGoXW7MU/cert.pem for problems
```

`/tmp/openssl-osx-ca.cGoXW7MU/cert.pem` is just a mile-long list of certificated.

Wht does it mean? What should I do? thanks.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$ brew update ; brew reinstall openssl

Comment: That did it, but what was causing the problem?

Comment: For me updating the "openssl-osx-ca" formula did the trick.